# Trying to get the Facebook authentication using python3.2

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to follow the steps mention here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/ 
to get the authentication from user. I execute the following python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
import os
import urllib
import json

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'type': 'device_code','client_id': 439862919363245,'scope':})
data = data.encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/device")
request.add_header("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8")
try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,data)
    httpcode = response.getcode()
    responseData = response.read()
    dataMap = json.loads(responseData.decode())
except Exception as e:
    print ("Exception : "+str(e))

if httpcode != 200:
    print('Error : code :'+httpcode+', data : '+data)
    sys.exit(1)

print("Success : ")
print(dataMap)
```

I get the following **OutPut:**

```
Exception : HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
Success : 
{'username': 'hamepal', 'first_name': 'Rakesh', 'last_name': 'Kumar', 'name': 'Rakesh Kumar', 'locale': 'en_GB', 'gender': 'male', 'id': '713371871'}

The output is really strange. According to document I should have received the data similar to as following.
{"code":"64a99b030985f39a93b2608a4713e758","user_code":"E5MV1N","verification_uri":"http://www.facebook.com/device","expires_in":1800,"interval":5}
```

Am I missing something here? I also try to replicate the request as given here 
http://oauth-device-demo.appspot.com/ But I couldn't get any success.

I tried to search over the net but couldn't get any thing working. Please help.
Any kind of help is greatly appreciated here.

**Edited:**
Now when I use the client_id same as given in the example then it works fine. According to notice put on the page, seems like they are still not supporting any other device yet. And I have to look for Authentication flow for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty clear that you not white-listed for usage of Device Authentication.

Citing the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/)

> we are currently testing Device Authentication with a limited number of partners. It is not currently available for general use, and we are not accepting additional applications for access.

The [OAuth 2.0 Device Authentication Flow demo](http://oauth-device-demo.appspot.com/) you refer to developed by [Simon Cross](http://99layers.com/sicross) (who is Facebook employee) and (probably?) allowed to use that flow.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the FB developer page it says ;

> Please note that we are currently testing Device Authentication with a limited number of partners. It is not currently available for general use, and we are not accepting additional applications for access.

This might be your problem